# How to differentiate string and regex from list in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am having a list like below which has string and regex patterns
`['sync', r'\1', r'\1', 'topper', r'\2', 'holder', 'average']`

I want to split the strings and regex patterns to separate list, like

`mystring = ['sync', 'topper', 'holder', 'average']` 
`myregex_pattern = [r'\1', r'\1', r'\2']`

How can I do that in python?

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more information: where is this list coming from? And what do you want to do next with the two lists? Thanks.

Comment: What are the characteristics of your strings and regex patterns? are regex patterns all in the form of \1,\2,\3...?

Answer (score 4):

The only possible difference between a string and a regular expression is that not all strings are valid regular expressions. Therefore, the easiest way to determine that is to simply try it and see (EAFP):

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['sync', r'\1', r'\1', 'topper', r'\2', 'holder', 'average']
>>> for ex in l:
...     try:
...             re.compile(ex)
...     except:
...             print(ex, 'fails.')
...
re.compile('sync')
\1 fails.
\1 fails.
re.compile('topper')
\2 fails.
re.compile('holder')
re.compile('average')
```

And now you see that your idea of a valid regex pattern is the complete opposite from what the interpreter thinks (which is what counts).

If you want to separate strings that were defined as literals with and without the raw string syntax, that is not possible, because the results are simply strings. It's like trying to separate `1.0` from `1.00` - they are the same number.